# Django Annotate using a model method

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm trying to do an annotate in this model, but considering the `get_is_secure` into the result.

```
class ScoringStudyLog(TimeStampedModel):
    scoring_status = models.CharField('Estudio', max_length=255,
    choices=_STATUS_CHOICES, default='pending')

    class Meta: # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """ Sets human readable name """
        verbose_name = "Registro de estudio"
        verbose_name_plural = "Histórico de estudios"

    def get_is_secure(self):
        return self.scoring_status == "approved"
```

How could I do a query like this?

```
indicators["studies_by_status"] = ScoringStudyLog.objects.filter(
    **studies_filters
).values('is_secure').annotate(times=Count('is_secure'))
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do with that query, methods are on application layer and not on database layer so they cannot be used for queries

Comment: I'd like to access the method result as a model field. Or find a similar way to do it.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when